# What is the effect of having window.matchMedia with a Listener in $(document).ready()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    mediaMatchMenu = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 860px)");
    mediaMatchMenu.addListener(doMatchMediaResult); 
});

function doMatchMediaResult(arg) { // "arg" is MediaQueryListEvent
    console.log("in doMatchMediaResult");
}
```

If I resize the browser, I see that the console log is only printed once when switching over from <860px to >860px in either direction, but not when changing the width within each of the two ranges (e.g., 800 <-> 700, or 1000 <-> 1200). Also, it does not get printed on startup in either case. So is the meaning of this code, **when the new width crosses the threshold compared to the old width during resizing** in either direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the listener is only invoked when the status changes. The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/addListener) says:

> The deprecated `addListener()` method of the MediaQueryList interface adds a listener to the MediaQueryListener that will run a custom callback function in response to the **media query status changing**.

(emphasis mine)

Note that this is deprecated, the preferred way to use it is to add an event listener for the `change` event.

It's not called when first create the `MediaQueryList`, since nothing has changed yet. You can use the [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/matches) property to test whether the document currently matches the query.